# Splitting multiple joined words without delimiters

Tags: java, string, replace, split

I'm building a word ranking system which should be noise-tolerant, meaning that it should work with words like *aaaaabbccccc*, where *aaaaa*, *bb* and *ccccc* are some random words.

The problem itself requires a dictionary, which I'm not allowed to use, but in my instances there are big chances to have the single words in the dataset, so I thought to exploit this information to create a splitter that works without an explicit dictionary.

What I'd like to do tho is to have this working in a single iteration while adding words to results map.

Here's a quick scenario of what I mean:

*input words*

```
word1
composedword1
1
abiggercomposedword1
bigger
abigger
```

- Step 1

  - Read *word1*
  - Check if *result* contains a word containing *word1* or a word contained by *word1*
  - No, add *word1* to *result*

*result:*

```
{word1}
```

- Step 2

  - Read *composedword1*
  - Check if *result* contains a word containing *composedword1* or a word contained by *composedword1*
  - Yes, *word1* is contained in *composedword1*
  - Add spaces before and after *word1* inside *composedword1*
  - Remove *word1* from *result*
  - Add *composed word1* to *result*

*result:*

```
{composed word1} // Note that this is still a single word!
```

- Step 3

  - Read *1*
  - Check if *result* contains a word containing *1* or a word contained by *1*
  - Yes, *1* is contained in *composed word1*
  - Add spaces before and after *1* inside *composed word1*
  - Remove *composed word1* from *result*
  - Add *composed word 1* to *result*

*result:*

```
{composed word 1}
```

Things work fine until the next step.

- Step 4

  - Read *abiggercomposedword1*
  - Check if *result* contains a word containing *abiggercomposedword1* or a word contained by *abiggercomposedword1*
  - **No, because *result* contains a single word separated by spaces. It would've worked if that word was separated in different strings.**

Now, given this scenario, here's the code that I'm using (the one working until step 4):

```
// Map between word and score
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> word : words.entrySet()) {
    boolean hasMergedWords = false;
    // result is the final HashMap, calling new to avoid concurrent modification
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> resultWord : new LinkedHashMap<>(result).entrySet()) {
        String wordToCheck = resultWord.getKey().trim();
        String currentWordToCheck = word.getKey().trim();
        if (currentWordToCheck.contains(wordToCheck)) {
            // Merge provided word into topWord
            result.put(currentWordToCheck.replace(wordToCheck, " " + wordToCheck + " ").trim().replaceAll(" +", " "), result.get(wordToCheck) + word.getValue());
            result.remove(wordToCheck);
            hasMergedWords = true;
        } else if (wordToCheck.contains(currentWordToCheck)) {
            result.put(wordToCheck.replace(currentWordToCheck, " " + currentWordToCheck + " ").trim().replaceAll(" +", " "), result.get(wordToCheck) + word.getValue());
            result.remove(wordToCheck);
            hasMergedWords = true;
        }
    }
    if (!hasMergedWords) {
        // Nothing was merged so we add current word
        result.put(word.getKey(), word.getValue());
    }
}
```

Finally, the question: can someone help me dealing with the case found in step 4? My first idea was to split each word in *result* using spaces as separators, but this will cause issues when merging their scores.

EDIT: expected result is `result = {a bigger composed word 1}`, a single string in which each word is separated by a space.

Comment: I'm not sure that approach would work, i.e. what if you words like "a"? You'd probably split things you'd not want to split then.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but those words are filtered in pre-processing. It may be quite long to explain, so let's assume that your case doesn't happen because I only receive words that I can split.

Comment: I also didn't thoroughly read your code but it seems like operating on a copy of `result` in the inner loop might cause problems. Wouldn't it be better to directly work on `result` so that any previous replacement is immediately visible`And btw, `String currentWordToCheck = word.getKey().trim();` should be in the outer loop and not the inner one. No need to trim more than once.

Comment: One more thing: I'm not quite sure what you want to achive in step 4. Do you want to get a match or not? If I understood your explanations correctly `abiggercomposedword1` would contain at least `composed`, `word` and `1` (the values in `result`) and thus should be split by those, no?

Comment: @Thomas Adding to `result` while iterating causes a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Nice catch about `currentWordToCheck`. I also added the expected result to OP.

Comment: Ah yes you're right. The iterator would allow for `remove()` but adding isn't that easy. Maybe you'd need a slightly different approach (I don't have the time to investigate atm though). Besides that, it seems like in step 4 `result` would contain only one key (`"composed word 1"`) which is wrong imo. If you split a word all the split parts should be separate keys, i.e. you should end up with `"composed", "word", "1"`. Then of course you need to adapt your approach for checking so that if you split an entry in `result` the next iteration immediately sees that.

Comment: @Thomas my explanation may have been wrong, but my goal is exactly to have a single string with words separated from spaces. You can see it as this problem: `input = #New #York #NewYork #NewYorkCity` (each hashtag is a separate string), `output = New York City` (as a single string).

Comment: You could still get that with single strings and then combining them again (or splitting the target string based on those).